Clipping buffers by Unique ID
I am doing my thesis on worldwide river discharge data availability.
I need to know how to cut buffers with their corresponding vector/polygon that have an unique ID.
I have stations worldwide with unique IDs and metadata.
I have made a selection of sub-basins that also each have their unique IDs.
I have made it so that each station also shares the ID of the sub-basin they are in.
I have made buffers around the stations that also contain the metadata and IDs of the station they are buffering.
Now I want to clip these buffers to the sub-basins with the corresponding IDs This is because I don't want the buffer to exist in an sub-basin polygon that is uncorrelated to the original sub-basin. However, I can't figure out how to do this. When I join attributes by location it doesn't seem to do anything new. When I clip them, it just clips the buffer by all sub-basins in the area.

As you can see the buffers reach over their sub-basin if there is a vector basin next to it. I want to cut each buffer ONLY by their corresponding sub-basin. Doing it manually per buffer is not possible as it contains over 10 000s of stations worldwide.

As you can see the buffer does have different HYBAS_ID if a part of it is in a different basin. I can select these individual parts with the information click option. I now need to know how to basically cut these parts off. I don't know how to select parts of the buffers that have the SAME HYBAS_ID as the vector below (sub-basin). If i know that i can just export the selected features like Pieter suggested.

 With a photo

You can do this like this:

calculate the intersection between both layers

on this result, use "select features by expression...", with as expression something like this: HYBAS_ID_BASIN = HYBAS_ID_BUFFER

export the selected features by rightclicking the "intersection" layer and choosing "Export"/"Save selected features as..."


What exactly do you mean by calculate the intersection between both layers? Im new to Qgis and cant find the function/tool.

@Sebastian: I added a screenshot where you can find it

When i do this it selects the entire layer, instead of just selecting the overlap in which the HYBAS_ID is the same. When selecting by attribute i only see one option there (which i set to HYBAS_ID) but it seems liek it just selects everything with an HYBAS_ID. The HYBAS_ID from the buffer does seems to differ when it is situated over another basin with a different HYBAS_ID. What am i missing

I added some more details and an extra screenshot in the answer...

[![As you can see the buffer does have different HYBAS_ID if a part of it is in a different basin. I can select these individual parts with the information click option. I now need to know how to basicly cut these parts off. I dont know how to select parts of the buffers that have the SAME HYBAS_ID as the vector below (sub-basin). If i know that i can just export the selected features.
With a photo [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/f5YZMst6.png

@sebastian: not sure what you mean. Subdividing the buffers into the parts that intersect different basins is what the first step in my post, "Intersection...", does.
